# Byte Array over BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a security researcher and I've come across the ability to send a byte array to a device causing the device/connection to crash.  I'm still familiarizing myself with the BLE protocol so while I think this seems off, I'm unsure. So, would this be considered a vulnerability?  Perhaps a DoS or overflow of some kind?

Sending a byte array.  I sent a flood of bytes which resulted in a disconnect/crash.  Are there generally checks in place to prevent this kind of thing?

Comment: Depends on device implementation. There is no problem with sending any number of bytes to a BLE device. But how it is processed dependsonly on the devices firmware and on protocol.

Comment: That makes sense, but should sending any number of bytes cause a disconnect/DoS?  Any device can connect and perform this action without any kind of authentication

Comment: "Should" according to what/who? The Bluetooth standard does not explicitly state "a device should not crash if being flooded with data", so the robustness is completely up to the manufacturer. It's of course a bad thing to have this type of crashes, but it's not against any standard. That said, good implementations have proper flow control mechanisms so this does not happen.

Comment: Fair, "should" according to some best practices at the very least.  Thanks for that information, I imagined there should be some kind of flow control to prevent this.

Comment: @m00dy No, it should not. You can not send more then MTU size. Even if you try it wll be truncated. Write operation (default one) does not guarantee data delivering so if you try to DDOS part of data will be simple lost. If you use Write With Reponse you can't actually DDOS because device may check each received packet and accept or reject it. You can send next packet until previous accepted/reject. Refer to GATT specification in Bluetooth Core.